# Can there be a case while /proc/cpuinfo file has several different model & model name fields?

Tags: cpu

I want to create script gathering CPU info from the server.
At the certain server output of file named in question title has 12 `model` and `model name` fields which are equally to each other. These case shown at the screenshot below.
Are the 12 instances no more than 12 cores of single physical CPU or there're 12 separate CPUs?

Result of grepping `model` word from `/proc/cpuinfo`

```
model           : 158
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2236 CPU @ 3.40GHz
model           : 158
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2236 CPU @ 3.40GHz
model           : 158
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2236 CPU @ 3.40GHz
model           : 158
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2236 CPU @ 3.40GHz
model           : 158
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2236 CPU @ 3.40GHz
model           : 158
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2236 CPU @ 3.40GHz
model           : 158
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2236 CPU @ 3.40GHz
model           : 158
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2236 CPU @ 3.40GHz
model           : 158
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2236 CPU @ 3.40GHz
model           : 158
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2236 CPU @ 3.40GHz
model           : 158
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2236 CPU @ 3.40GHz
model           : 158
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2236 CPU @ 3.40GHz
```

Comment: @muru 
I use screenshot to not share with search systems text info about specific CPUs cause it's not the server I own.
I'm sorry for the incovenience.

Comment: @muru Hm. It is, I've didn't think about such info inside Marcus answer. So you're right. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Thanks for that!

Comment: "Are the 12 instances no more than 12 cores of single physical CPU or there're 12 separate CPUs?" – How do you define "separate CPU" and "physical CPU"? What difference does it make to you? In other words: what do you need this information for? What are you going to do with this information? What decisions are you going to make based on this information?

Comment: @JörgWMittag This information is going to the table of clients infrastracture we support. It's not more than docs for our admins and wiki they use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither. These are 12 Hyperthreads of 6 Cores of 1 Xeon E-2236.

I know that from reading [intel's product data sheet](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/191040/intel-xeon-e2236-processor-12m-cache-3-40-ghz/specifications.html).

You could get more detailed information by asking `lscpu`, which lists the number of CPUs, cores and threads.

Yours is a very small, very uniform Xeon (as far as Xeons go). Would you have a more complex system with multiple sockets, containing potentially different CPUs or CPUs with different core configurations, different PCIe buses, and memory topologies, i.e., NUMA, the `lstopo` program would be more what you need to learn how your computer's structured (package containing that is usually called `hwloc` or `hwloc-gui`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I'll search such info in the official docs next time :)

Comment: @palmasd1 the official docs wouldn't tell you what your memory topology looks like; in systems with mutliple CPU sockets, it's not inherently so that every CPU core can access all memory at the same speed. So, things like `lscpu` and `lstopo` make a lot of sense